# Delete all data on Facebook without having an account

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

From the latest updates to security and data-protection there is now a way to delete all private data a company such as Facebook has collected together with the ability to get the collected data.

I never had a personal account on Facebook, however I had one on WhatsApp that's part of Facebook and shares its data with that company. Anyway - even without having an active account on neither Facebook nor WhatsApp - there's of course much information about myself - e.g. data that friends of mine shared that cover me, or even data concerning the time where I had an account for WhatsApp.

Of course I can,'t simply write to Facebook "please delete my account and all its related data", because there is no account - at least to publicly accessible one.

Is there any way to contact the support for such kind of things?